# ffmpeg: no matches found: -map[v]

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to merge 4 videos in split-screen with their audio together.

```
./ffmpeg -i ./clip11.mp4 -i ./clip21.mp4 -i ./clip31.mp4 -i ./clip41.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[top];[2:v][3:v]hstack=inputs=2[bottom];[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[v];amerge=inputs=4[a]" -map[v] -map[a] ./split21.mp4
```

I try tried and run the code, but it shows this as an error.

```
zsh: no matches found: -map[v]
```

I don't know whether my machine cannot configure the "map" because it happens the same thing when I tried to do "concat". I do not know what else to change about. I typed it out on the latest Mac, but surprisingly my friend that have an older version of Mac got the code working. Help.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's zsh that complains that a file pattern is not matching any file. Try to add a space and put quotes around the patterns like this `-map "[v]" -map "[a]"` to no expand them.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some spaces to separate the option from the value.

Use `-map "[v]" -map "[a]"`.

The quotes are not necessary in this case but will allow you to use spaces in your label names if desired.

Comment: You saved me with the double quotes. Without double quotes does not work on MacOS.